# Ruby map JSON multiple but not all attributes with RABL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rabl

I have the following Rabl in my views:

```
node(:relations) do |p|
  related = p.relations.pluck(:related_to_id)
  Spree::Product.find(related)
end
```

This renders the following:

```
"relations": [
{
"product": {
"id": 2,
"name": "T-SHIRT",
"description": "Awesome T shirts"
"created_at": "..."
"updated_at: "..."
 .
 .
 .
 bunch of other columns that I don't need.
```

My question is how do I only grab `:name` and `:description`, so that the JSON output looks like:

```
"relations": [
    {
    "product": {
    "name": "T-SHIRT",
    "description": "Awesome T shirts"
    }
 ]
```

I've tried mapping it, `Spree::Product.find(related).map { |r| [r.name, r.description] }`

But that returns only the values, like so:

```
"relations": [
"T-SHIRT",
"Awesome T shirts"
]
```

Thank you for your help!

**UPDATE**:

When I write:

```
child :related_products do
  attributes :name, :description
end
```

I get:

```
"spree_relations": [
{}
]
```

Link to model:

https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_related_products/blob/master/app/models/spree/relation.rb

Comment: Can you use `.select` like `Spree::Product.select("name, description")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there probably multiple ways to do it.

You can use rails `#as_json` method.

```
node(:relations) do |p|
  related = p.relations.pluck(:related_to_id)
  Spree::Product.find(related).as_json(only: [:name, :description])
end
```

Or you can try to do it the rabl way.

```
child :related_products do
  attributes :name, :description
end
```

But for this you might need to change your model a bit.

Comment: I prefer the rabl way, I updated the question, do I need to make it `belongs_to :product`

Comment: Nevermind. It seems you must use the relation type. For exemple `product.up_sells`